# Unable to find 5 sec slot timing in code base

Tags: consensus, scp

I was trying to understand the stellar code base and was looking for a place where `5 sec` slot timing is hardcoded (if I am not wrong). But unable to find that, instead in `ovalayManagerImpl.cpp` file I found that timer elapsed at every `2 sec`.

```
mTimer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::seconds(2));
```

Am I looking at incorrect file? Also, my second question is what is the rational behind the 5 sec slot timing ?

Comment: If I recall correctly from keybase, you found that this is the correct place. Right?

Comment: @Synesso this is not the correct file it seems. The ledger closing time is set from `config.cpp` file. look at my answer below. now I have to understand why `mTimer` is set to `2` sec then in OverlayManagerImpl.cpp file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found method which returns the expected ledger closing time,

```
std::chrono::seconds
Config::getExpectedLedgerCloseTime() const
{
    if (ARTIFICIALLY_SET_CLOSE_TIME_FOR_TESTING)
    {
        return std::chrono::seconds{ARTIFICIALLY_SET_CLOSE_TIME_FOR_TESTING};
    }
    if (ARTIFICIALLY_ACCELERATE_TIME_FOR_TESTING)
    {
        return std::chrono::seconds{1};
    }
    return Herder::EXP_LEDGER_TIMESPAN_SECONDS;
}
```

and the value for `EXP_LEDGER_TIMESPAN_SECONDS` is set to `5` sec 
 - `std::chrono::seconds const Herder::EXP_LEDGER_TIMESPAN_SECONDS(5);`